# Java3d applet won't render on Lion

Tags: macos, graphics, java, web-browser

I have no idea what's the problem, but Java3D isn't rendering in applets.

For example if I go to this page: http://www.java3d.org/howto.html and I see the first applet but not the second one.

Also the java console gives the the next code:

```
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition value null
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@609903f4
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@6536d9d8
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://www.java3d.org/, version: null]
network: Cache entry found [url: http://www.java3d.org/AJava3dApplet.class, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
network: Connecting http://www.java3d.org/AJava3dApplet.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://www.java3d.org:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: ResponseCode for http://www.java3d.org/AJava3dApplet.class : 304
network: Encoding for http://www.java3d.org/AJava3dApplet.class : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://www.java3d.org/AJava3dApplet.class
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://www.java3d.org/, version: null]
network: Cache entry found [url: http://www.java3d.org/AnApplet.class, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
network: Connecting http://www.java3d.org/AnApplet.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://www.java3d.org:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: ResponseCode for http://www.java3d.org/AnApplet.class : 304
network: Encoding for http://www.java3d.org/AnApplet.class : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://www.java3d.org/AnApplet.class
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 4466644 us, pluginInit dt 8044826 us, TotalTime: 12511470 us
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 4466644 us, pluginInit dt 8065627 us, TotalTime: 12532271 us
network: Cache entry found [url: http://www.java3d.org/AJava3dApplet$1.class, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
network: Connecting http://www.java3d.org/AJava3dApplet$1.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://www.java3d.org:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: ResponseCode for http://www.java3d.org/AJava3dApplet$1.class : 304
network: Encoding for http://www.java3d.org/AJava3dApplet$1.class : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://www.java3d.org/AJava3dApplet$1.class
network: Cache entry found [url: http://www.java3d.org/AnApplet$1.class, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
network: Connecting http://www.java3d.org/AnApplet$1.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://www.java3d.org:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: ResponseCode for http://www.java3d.org/AnApplet$1.class : 304
network: Encoding for http://www.java3d.org/AnApplet$1.class : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://www.java3d.org/AnApplet$1.class
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@6536d9d8
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@609903f4
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
```

So the 2 apples are launched but I don't see the second one.
Safari, Firefox, and Google Chrome behave the same.

I've successfully launched Java App with Graphics3D but applet won't show up. I'll be very thankful for a solution.

Comment: "If you can't see a red ball in a black square, you need to install Java 3D". Did you install it? I guess you did, because apps work. But maybe you installed it in a way that the applet plugin cannot see it?

Comment: Maybe also try Stackoverflow

Comment: @Thilo applet can see it. Because I had exceptions first and then when I moved the **j3d** files into the correct locations app started to launch. But I can't see the 3D content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is that new Java plugin2 does not support Java3D and JOGL: [source](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/CrossPlatform/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate2LeopardUpdate7RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009967-CH4-SW1).